# Allow users to access admin section with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I can allow users to access the admin section of my site based on IP address, and redirect the others to "Page not Found" page with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.67\.890$
RewriteRule (.*) - [R=404,L]
```

I wonder if it is possible to add a new rule to allow also users trying to access "/admin/index.php?mikey=mouse" no matter which IP address they are coming from, and redirect the others.

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/index.php?mikey=mouse$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.67\.890$
RewriteRule (.*) - [R=404,L]
```

It doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, you can check for query string contents as well using a RewriteCond, by using the corresponding environment variable.

Comment: RewriteConds are joined with a logical AND by default, you need to use the `[OR]` flag if you want to change that. In that regard, it might make more sense if you leave the first part of checking if the path starts with `admin` to the RewriteRule pattern here. (Then you won’t have to repeat the first condition, so that it applies in combination with the new one you are about to add as well.)